# python. Are lists considered global when passed to a function?

Tags: python, list

```
keeplist1= ['GenderDesc','MartialStatusDesc','castegroup']
dummylist1= 'castegroup'

def funky(keeplist,dummylist):

        keeplist.remove(dummylist)
        print keeplist

funky(keeplist1,dummylist1)
```

output: ['GenderDesc', 'MartialStatusDesc']

```
print keeplist1
```

output: ['GenderDesc', 'MartialStatusDesc']

Both the print statements give the same output. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Briefly: scope isn't really involved. You just passed in and mutated a mutable object.

Comment: Yes that is expected behaviour..List elements can be changed inside a function. any changes made to list elements in a function can be reflected in a list which is outside of function. You can refer the question suggested by TigerhawkT3